# Nautilus stopped working, file manager, desktop items vanished

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, nautilus

I was running Ubuntu 18.04 and got an automatic upgrade message. I started the upgrade process but I aborted it midway. From then on wards my desktop icons became weird in appearance.  Today, I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and then after that my nautilus stopped working and I couldn't open the file manager, not could see any desktop items.

I further did `sudo apt upgrade` and it got upgraded to 20.04 but my nautilus problem remained. Hence from the terminal, I decide too purge the nautilus and reinstall it. It gave the error

```
gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 is to be installed 
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I also ran the following command as suggested :

```
$ apt-cache policy gsettings-desktop-schema mutter nautilus
mutter:
  Installed: 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2
  Candidate: 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Version table:
     3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.36.1-3ubuntu3 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.5
  Candidate: 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.36.1.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.5 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
N: Unable to locate package gsettings-desktop-schema
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy gsettings-desktop-schema mutter nautilus` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1303258/edit).

Comment: I have edited my question with the command you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get all updates with newest dependencies for your current system by executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```